J3E modem in a 25kHz FM signal
Is there a widely used term for a communication system that takes the 3kHz output of a psk data-modem (intended for SSB-SC, or J3E, radio transmission) and transmits it on 25kHz FM voice radio channel?
Is there a formal ITU classification for this kind of emission? Technically there is no subcarrier because it is a suppressed carrier signal, so it wouldn't be right to classify it as ITU class F2D ("F- Frequency modulation, 2 - a single channel containing quantized or digital information with the use of a modulating sub-carrier"), but I have the impression that ITU class F1D ("[...]digital information without the use of a modulating sub-carrier") refers to FSK modulations only. The mere mention of a frequency modulated PSK signal sounds like an oxymoron to me.
Are there technical references to the advantages or disadvantages of this type of emission when compared to wide band SSB. It seems to be wasteful of RF band, short ranged and vulnerable to interference, but I'm just guessing.


Is there a widely used term for a communication system that takes the 3kHz output of a psk data-modem (intended for SSB-SC, or J3E, radio transmission) and transmits it on 25kHz FM voice radio channel?

I'd call it A-PSK, and I'd also call it "weird".
There are PSK systems that work in the audio signal, by being modulated onto a carrier higher in frequency than the bandwidth primary (audio) signal, then added to said audio signal. RDS, the thing that shows you station infos and traffic emergencies on your car radio (at least in Europe) is exactly that. But that's really a legacy crutch necessary because the design forced modulation on the same carrier as the primary audio signal.

Are there technical references to the advantages or disadvantages of this type of emission when compared to wide band SSB.

We can talk about that, and if you present us with the parameters (deviation, mostly) of your FM transmitter, we can even experimentally (or mathematically, though that's just annoying for pulse-shaped input to an FM demodulator) determine the spectral efficiency (bit/s per Hz), and I can promise it's going to be a pretty low number.
Directly modulating your PSK signal as is onto the intended carrier would have exactly your data bit rate / 3 kHz as spectral efficiency.

It seems to be wasteful of RF band, short ranged and vulnerable to interference, but I'm just guessing.

I'd agree with that. Though there's technically nothing impossible about putting PSK into an FM modulator, it has no technical advantages, as far as I can tell. On the contrary, audio-optimized FM transmitters and receivers have pre-emphasis and de-emphasis filters, respectively, with defined amplitude, but pretty arbitrary phase response; this is not going to be great for your PSK-observable EVM.
Generally, if you want to transmit 3 kHz wide PSK, do that; why would you even want to put it through an FM transmitter? It's already a constant-envelope modulation, it's got loss bandwidth than your FM would have, and still easier to demodulate for a modern receiver system.

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't give more details for ethical reasons. I'd like to simulate its performance on different channel models. I have forgotten everything about how to evaluate the channel capacity of an FM channel.

no details, no help. For ethical reasons. And also, because it's simply impossible.

note that asking about properties of the design of specific confidential systems definitely leaves the scope of this site, which is a) general questions about theory of radio and b) amateur radio, which by definition is open.
